# Using writeAllBytes method without determine specific path

Tags: pdf-viewer

I want to use writeAllBytes Method without determine specific path
because I don't save the pdf file in pc.

my try

```
string strSQL = "SELECT StorePDF FROM TB WHERE FileName='" + tbFilePath.Text + "'";
            OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn);
            cmd2.Connection = conn;                
            conn.Open();
            Byte[] oleBytes = (Byte[])cmd2.ExecuteScalar();                
            File.WriteAllBytes("aaa.pdf", oleBytes.Skip(0).ToArray());
            pdfViewer1.FileName = "aaa.pdf";
```

I want replace path "aaa.pdf" with pdfViewer1.FileName directly

Answer (score 0):

```
string pdfName = "C:\myPdfFiles\20170301\aaa.pdf";
string strSQL = "SELECT StorePDF FROM TB WHERE FileName='" + tbFilePath.Text + "'";
            OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn);
            cmd2.Connection = conn;                
            conn.Open();
            Byte[] oleBytes = (Byte[])cmd2.ExecuteScalar();                
            File.WriteAllBytes(pdfName, oleBytes.Skip(0).ToArray());
            pdfViewer1.FileName = pdfName;
?¡
```

Comment: this is the same idea, this will save the file in the path of the program

Comment: Instructions are unclear. You don't want to save the file in the path of the program? Specify a full path then, imma correct my answer.

Comment: no no , i want to save in memory for example not in any place of the computer because i don't want any one to access this file

Comment: Does "pdfViewer1" object has a method to render from memory ?If not well, you should lock the file you create and then open it.